# tfs errors during nuget execution

Tags: tfs, nuget

During nuget package installation I get a lot of tfs errors like:

```
"The item  could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it."
```

For every file in the package. What it is? Why tfs tires to access that files at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked in the packages to TFS? if the packages are under source control they will be read only and won't be able to be updated. Enable NuGet restore either on the solution (old way) or use the new way (see NuGet.org) and remove the packages from source control

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it contained the information to determine the 'new way' or the 'old way' and what that actually means.